# SQL Server Partitioning - Unique Index Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-partitioning

I have a table that is partitioned by TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME.

Table has a column: ID.

I want to create a unique index for ID on partition scheme as:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID_ON_PS_DATETIME] ON [CRD].[TRANSACTION] 
(
    [ID] ASC
) ON [PS_DATETIME_WEEKLY]([TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME])
```

but SQL says "Partition column for a unique index must be a subset of index key".

**I really don't need TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME column in this index.**

How can I create the index without using TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME column?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two choices: you create a **NON**-partitioned index, or you **MUST** include the partitioning key in a partitioned index:

- Non-partitioned index

  ```
  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID_ON_PS_DATETIME] ON [CRD].[TRANSACTION] 
  (
      [ID] ASC
  ) ON PRIMARY
  ```

**OR**

- Partitioned index that includes the partitioning key

  ```
  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID_ON_PS_DATETIME] ON [CRD].[TRANSACTION] 
  (
      [ID] ASC,
      TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME
  ) ON [PS_DATETIME_WEEKLY]([TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME])
  ```

Comment: For SQL Server 2017, the syntax for example 1 is slightly changed:

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID_ON_PS_DATETIME] ON [CRD].[TRANSACTION] 
(
    [ID] ASC
) ON "PRIMARY"

Notice the quotes (") around "PRIMARY". I got syntax error otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

From the TechNet Microsoft page

> When partitioning a unique index (clustered or nonclustered), the
> partitioning column must be chosen from among those used in the unique
> index key. If it is not possible for the partitioning column to be
> included in the unique key, you must use a DML trigger instead to
> enforce uniqueness.

So to implement a workaround you can check this link out... one workaround from the blog and another one in the comments

[Dealing with Unique Columns when Using Table Partitioning](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/dealing-with-unique-columns-when-using-table-partitioning/ba-p/333995)