# Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error on my PK and I can't figure out how to fix it. I need the PK to align with the partition storage too.

> Column 'SizedTime' is partitioning column of the index
>   'PK_CDR_Inbound_1'. Partition columns for a unique index must be a
>   subset of the index key.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CDR_Inbound]  
ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CDR_Inbound_1] 
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [UUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)


GO
```

I need this to be a PK not an index. the other question the answer was a index.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710173/sql-server-partitioning-unique-index-error

Comment: @Serpiton Don't just link, vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CDR_Inbound]  
ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CDR_Inbound_1] 
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [UUID] ASC,
**Sizedtime**
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
**on cdr(sizedtime)**
```

Just needed to add the partition key to the PK and then added the ON statement afterwards